# laravel artisan command throwed `Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted` error

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, out-of-memory, laravel-artisan

In my laravel 5.4 project, I can not run `php artisan` command. An `Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted` error occured. The website can be view properly in the browser, and laravel.log is also empty, but `artisan` command in the terminal failed,like this:

```
➜  laravel git:(dev) ✗ php artisan

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php on line 120
```

It seems like the memory is not enough, I set bigger value for `memory_limit`,like this:

```
➜  laravel git:(dev) ✗ php -i |grep memory_limit

memory_limit => 2048MB => 2048MB
```

But it did not work,could anyone help me, please?

Comment: ```sudo vim /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
memory_limit = -1```

Comment: I had this issue too, and doing `memory_limit = -1` in the php.ini file for both the CLI and php-fpm solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got this type of error as laravel could not connect to Database. In Laravel 5.4, if database is not connected, it take lot of memory. I think, this is the bug in 5.4.

In general, to increase the memory limit, goto terminal and type
"php --ini".
This will show as
$ php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

This will show the location of php.ini file in your system.

2) Then open php.ini file in vi search for memory_limit using '/' in command mode. Then edit the line by pressing 'i' and memory_limit=2000:M.

3) press esc and type ":wq" (To save and quit)

Answer (score 1):

Locate your php.ini file by writing `php --ini` in the console (in my case it is located in `/etc/php/7.2/cli/`). Open php.ini, locate the line that sets `memory_limit`, and set it equal to `-1` (`memory_limit=-1)`.

Comment: worked for me, thanks. i don't recommend -1, but that's up to you. :)